# PHPUnit test of Symfony CLI command falling over when accessing 3rd party API

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, testing, phpunit, symfony-2.8

I have a PHPUnit test for my Symfony 2 application which is falling over at the following line:

`if ($subscriptions = $subscriptionEngine->getAllSubscriptions($site->getOwner())) {`

The error is:

`Sorry, we couldn't find the site SITEKEY`

I can see why this is, as my `parameters.yml.dist` contains the following:

`subscriptionengine.site: SITEKEY`

My question is should I create a test API Key/Site Key for testing or should I simply not be testing this at all?

The test is testing calling a Symfony CLI command which calls this third party API amongst other things. Is my approach wrong or is it as simple as creating test keys for use by PHPUnit only?

Comment: Why not just mock the subscription engine and its response so you can run it without having to access the 3rd-party API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works.

```
$subEngine = $this->getMockBuilder('\AppBundle\Services\SubEngine')
->disableOriginalConstructor()
->getMock();
$subEngine->expects($this->once())->method('getAllSubscriptions');
```

Credit to the comment above from Jason Roman and [scyrma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3876854/scyrma) for the code.